# How to change the Spring boot server time after it has been started

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jodatime

I am building an application using spring boot which has couple of scheduling tasks which are executed one month after it is created. For testing this service, I need to change the server time to a time after one month, when the server is running. Can you please guide through the steps of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, i would suggest you to create your service method with Date as parameter.
ex :

```
public void myScheduledTack(){
    myDate = getCurrentDate();

    myService.myMethod(myDate);
}
public getCurrentDate(){
 return new Date();
}
```

With this pattern, you could mock the getCurrentDate method and test your service.

Comment: I need to change the time on a permanent basis on the server. I don't think your approach will accomplish that.